# Send the count of rows of each tables in kdb q and email the o/p without using qmail

Tags: database, email, kdb

There is a table with the count of all the row values
h"QUERY"

How should the output be sent as an email everyday in a particular timing say UTC 5:00PM

I tried

```
system"mail -s "\d"\ -q filename abc@gmail.com"
.mail.send[dict] //dict has dict:`to`cc`subject`body!(`$("abc@gmail.com);"s"$();"count";h"query");
```

This keeps on loading, but doesn’t send any email to any specified account.

Comment: Have you tested a basic `sendmail` call to confirm it works outside of q? .i.e `echo "Subject: Testing does this arrive" | sendmail -v abc.gmail.com`

Comment: the above code works, i am able to send the send mail using the above comment, how can we send two tables at a time using the same system sendmail command. please help  @rianoc